# resolutionStrategy.force stop working after upgrade gradle version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
}
```

I use this to force all dependencies using particular version of `support-annotations`, however it stop working after upgrading gradle version from `2.14` to `3.3`

This is the error I'm getting

> Gradle sync failed: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:scripts' after it has been resolved.
>                   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)